# Spring Data Rest: Null Pointer If-Modified-Since Header Present and Resource Not Auditable

Tags: java, spring-data-rest

If a Client makes a request for a Resource and specifies the `If-Modified-Since` header when the mapped Entity does not have any of the Spring Data JPA auditing annotations (`@CreatedBy`, `@LastModifiedBy`, `@CreatedDate`, `@LastModifiedDate` ) then this appears to result in a null-pointer exception in the class org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.HttpHeadersPreparer:

```
public boolean isObjectStillValid(Object source, HttpHeaders headers) {

    Assert.notNull(source, "Source object must not be null!");
    Assert.notNull(headers, "HttpHeaders must not be null!");

    if (headers.getIfModifiedSince() == -1) {
        return false;
    }

    //THE WRAPPER IS NULL IF NO AUDITING ANNOTATIONS PRESENT
    AuditableBeanWrapper wrapper = auditableBeanWrapperFactory.getBeanWrapperFor(source);
    long current = wrapper.getLastModifiedDate().getTimeInMillis() / 1000 * 1000;

    return current <= headers.getIfModifiedSince();
}
```

Is this a bug and, short of adding a field to the Entity to prevent this, is there any other workround.

Answer (score 0):

If fetching the entity doesn't emit a `Last-Modified` header, then I would say this is a bug in the client, not SDR.

If none of your entities support `Last-Modified`, maybe create a filter that strips `If-Modified-Since` from the request or catches it early and responds appropriately.

All of that said, I also don't think a NPE is acceptable and a SDR bug should be filed.